# Can someone help me out here. With reference to the 0 property, additive and scalar property?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

\begin{equation}
\text { Show that the set } A=\left\{\left[ \begin{array}{l}{y_{1}} \\ {y_{2}} \\ {y_{3}}\end{array}\right] | y_{1}=y_{2}, y_{3}=2 y_{2}\right\} \text { is a subspace of } R^{3} .
\end{equation}

I was able to let all elements of the vector be equal to 0 and this showed that the zero vector is indeed in the set A.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. To get help, please [edit] the question to show us what you can do and where you are stuck. To start with, can you show that the vector $(0,0,0)$ is in $A$?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is the set of vectors $ y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)^t$ such that the following conditions are fullfilled: 
$$ \textbf{1) } y_1 = y_2 $$
$$ \textbf{2) }  y_3 = 2 y_2 $$

This means that the first coordinate of your vector must be the same as the second, and the third must be two times the second one.

Let us check if the vector $ 0 = (0,0,0) $ satisfies the properties:

$ 0 = 0 $ so the second coordinate is equal to the first, and $ 0 = 2 (0) $ so the third coordinate is twice the second. So $ 0 \in A $.

Now let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3), z = (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in A $ (Let both be elements of $A$).

$ x + z = (x_1+z_1, x_2+z_2,x_3+z_3) $ we need to check if this vector satisfies the conditions.

For the first, as $x,z \in A$,  $x_1  = x_2, z_1 = z_2 $ so $ x_1 + z_1 = z_2 + z_2$ and so $x+z$ fullfills the first criterion.

For the second one, it's basically the same: $ x_3 = 2 x_2,z_3 = 2 z_2 $ and so 
$ x_3 + z_3 = 2 x_2 + 2 z_2 = 2 (x_2 + z_2) $ which means that the third coordinate of $x+z$ is twice the second.

For the scalar it is similar. $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, x \in A $ 
$ \alpha x = (\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2, \alpha x_3 ) $ so 
$$ \alpha x_1 = \alpha x_2 \text{ because } x_1 = x_2 $$
$$  \alpha x_3 = 2 \alpha x_2 \text{ because } x_3 = 2 x_2 $$

Therefore: $0$ is an element of $A$ and $A$ is closed under scalar and aditive operations, so it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$